# vscode ssh с использованием passphrase для ключа

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh-key

Не получается подключиться к удаленному серверу в vscode через ssh. При создании ключа добавил пароль (passphrase), через PuTTY подключаюсь без проблем, а вот vscode ни в какую.

**Настройки ssh подключения в vscode:**

```
Host host
  HostName <host_ip>
  User user
  IdentityFile <путь до ppk ключа>\key.ppk
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Так же пробовал указать путь до открытого ключа (который *.pub)